# React - Display all items inside localStorage as a Material UI List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, material-ui, local-storage

I have localStorage with multiple items on it. I want to retrieve all of them and display it on a `<ListItem>` Material UI.

Here's my current code:

```
function saveJob(key, value) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

function saveJob is basically just save the value along with unique key.
The content of the localStorage would be something like this:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Technician |
| 2 | Plumber |

How I retrieved the items back:

```
var savedJobs = [];
useEffect(() => {
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = keys.length;

    while (i--) {
        savedJobs.push(localStorage.getItem(keys[i]));
    }

    return savedJobs;
}, [])
```

Now onto the problem, I tried to display it in a functional component through `<ListItem>` Material UI like the following:

```
<List>
    {savedJobs.map((job) => (
    <ListItem key={job.Key} disablePadding>
    <ListItemButton>
      <ListItemText  primary={job.Value} />
    </ListItemButton>
  </ListItem>
    ))}
</List>
```

This is not working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't trigger rerender when a local variable in a function component was changed. It will be rerendered when: the state has changed, props were changed or the parent component was rerendered.

You should put your `savedJobs` to state and write

> const [savedJobs, setSavedJobs] = useState([]);

instead of

> var savedJobs = [];

Answer (score 0):

You need state to store the data you retrieve from localstorage. Instead of your `savedJobs` var outside of your `useEffect`, create an array inside the hook and then update your state with this data. Here's an example:

```
  // Initiate your state as an empty array.
  const [savedJobs, setSavedJobs] = useState([]);

  // Used as an example instead of localstorage.
  const example = ["foo", "bar"];

  useEffect(() => {
    let jobs = [];
    let keys = Object.keys(example),
      i = keys.length;
    while (i--) {
      jobs.push(example[i]);
    }
    setSavedJobs(jobs);
  }, [example]);

  return <>{savedJobs.map((job) => job)}</>;
```

Or see this [interactive example](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-darkness-4lvvq2?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

First I would check what is inside your savedJobs array.
It seems that savedJobs would look like this:

savedJobs = ['Technician', 'Plumber'];

On the other hand, you are mapping and getting the value like so:
{job.Key} & {job.Value}

Try:

```
<List>
    {savedJobs.map((job, i) => (
    <ListItem key={i} disablePadding>
    <ListItemButton>
      <ListItemText  primary={job} />
    </ListItemButton>
  </ListItem>
    ))}
</List>
```

ps: you should not use `i` as a key, but I let you figuring out what value you want there.

If you want to use {job.key} and {job.value}, you need to `push` an object like so:

```
  
  savedJobs.push({key: i, value: localStorage.getItem(keys[i])});
```